# I've got an incorrect output for 13 factorial,how do i fix this?

Tags: c

My output
13!=1932053504

Expected output
13!=6227020800

I tried using int,long int but still the output remains the same

```
long int fact(long int num);
int main(){
    long int n;
    printf("Enter a number to find factorial: ");
    scanf("%ld",&n);
    printf("%ld!= %ld",n,fact(n));
}
long int fact(long int n){
    if(n>=1)
        return n*fact(n-1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Output:
13!=1932053504

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Sorry my bad,i made changes

Comment: Integer overflow? What is the size of `long` on your system? I'll bet it's four bytes (32 bits). Use `unsigned long long` instead.

Comment: But i have a 64 bit OS?

Comment: Yes, SomeProgrammerDude is right. I pasted your code into https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler and I got 6227020800. Your C compiler treats long as 32 bits.

Comment: Except `char` (`sizeof(char)` is always equal to `1`), the size of all types can vary from compiler to compiler. GCC have 64-bit `long` on 64-bit systems, while VC++ have 32-bit `long` on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Is there any way to extend my compiler to 64bits?

Comment: @Kevin Use a type that's guaranteed to be at least 64 bits? Like `unsigned long long` as I mentioned before.

Comment: Try using `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` if you want a bit more precision (check to see if your compiler supports it).  Use `%lld` or `%llu` to print.

Comment: Look in the file `limits.h` - it will tell you how big your sizes are. C only provides minimum guarantees on the sizes. It guarantees the largest long int is at least 2147483647. Look in that file for the value `LONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 3):

The expected value exceeds 32 bits, what you get is the actual result trimmed to 32 bits:

```
1932053504 equals (6227020800 & 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

You'll have to verify capacity of `int` and `long int` in your environment, e.g. with `print`-ing their `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `long long int` to make calculations on 64 bits. If you break that barrier also, you need to do more complicated stuff.

Note: use `long` twice, it is not a mistake - provided that the compiler supports 64-bit architectures.

If you are not interested in negative numbers, you can use `unsigned long long int` for some extra "comfort".

Comment: Note however, this will extend the domain from twelve just to twenty: 20!≈2.4×10^18 and 21!≈51×10^18, while 2^64≈18.4×10^18.

Comment: True, that's why complicated stuff is needed for even bigger numbers. E.g., GNU MP